# ParseError: Unexpected token with Browserify and template files

Tags: javascript, node.js, backbone.js, handlebars.js, jst

I'm developing a site using Backbone and I have Watchify running to bundle the application. Everything works fine with the javascript modules, but I am having a problem with .hbs templates, with Watchify throwing parse errors when processing the template files. These are really simple templates, the one in question literally contains only this html:

```
<p>Hello world!</p>
<ul id="menu">
</ul>
```

I have installed hbsfy am invoking it thusly:

```
watchify ./app/main.js -t hbsfy -o static/js/bundle.js -v
```

The error returned:

```
/home/***/***/backbone_app/app/node_modules/templates/layout.hbs:1
        <p>Hello world!</p>
        ^
ParseError: Unexpected token
```

I've read over the docs and looked in several locations online and honestly can't see what I am doing wrong here. Thanks for any insight you can offer.

Answer (score 1):

Your template is under `node_modules`. Browserify transforms only apply to "top-level" files, i.e. files from your app, not of your dependencies.

Instead try the `--global-transform` flag:

```
watchify -g hbsfy ./app/main.js -o static/js/bundle.js -v
```

Comment: do you know how i can do this within the gulpfile.js file?

Answer (score 0):

Try this instead

```
watchify -t hbsfy ./app/main.js -o static/js/bundle.js -v
```